# Running Code every 11 seconds

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase-realtime-database, server

I'm am new to server technology and dont really understand how they work (hope you could shed some light on this as well).
But basically my problem is I have a Firebase Database which i need to update every 20 seconds the whole day. This is the way I think i should solve the problem. I need to send a HTTP POST request to the firebase database every 20 sec. This means I need to have a server where I run a piece of code sending the HTTP request every 20s. Im not sure if this is the right way to do it, and even if it is how to implement it.
Some questions i have are

- I definitely need to create a server for this right? and if so what platform is recommended to write my server code? (preferable free platforms)
  I have tried reading up on the platforms available such as AWS, Google Cloud but dont really get the terminology used. Are there any tutorials for this available?

I am really lost, and have been stuck on this for some time, any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: An ideal solution will probably depend on the purpose and nature of the 20 second update.  For example: how do you know what to send in the update, and why 20 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable by leveraging [Cloud Watch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html) specifically using a  [Rate Expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html#RateExpressions) that invokes a [SNS topic](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/) which can then hit your HTTP endpoint.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you try and keep everything within Firebase.  Create a firebase cloud function that sends the HTTP request for the update, and use [Firebase functions-cron](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html) that is a cron like scheduler to schedule.